# Crash when pressing a button that changes an image

Tags: swift

My app crashes when pressing this button, on the `let`, why? It shows me the image literal, so theoretically, it finds the image, right? If I choose another image it works just fine. Don't know what's happening.

This is the error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1eb5bbb2c)
```

And this the function:

```
@IBAction func btnMuteMicPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let buttonImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3-1")

    btnMuteMic.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: check the `@IBOutlet` connection of `btnMuteMic`

Comment: Uh, did you accidentally set a breakpoint on that line? Is there a blue arrow to the left of the code? If so click on the blue arrow and drag it to the right to delete it.

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht I don't see anything strange. Everything looks good.

Comment: @vacawama Nope. No breakpoint anywhere.

Comment: Try highlighting that whole function, cut it and paste it back.  Then run it again.  Any different results?

Comment: @vacawama No, same thing unfortunately.

Comment: if it's working with other images, try removing this specific one and adding again, make sure your project target is checked.

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht Did that. Same thing. It's very weird.

Comment: Try using `let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "group3-1")`.  Does that work?  Is it `nil`?

Comment: @vacawama The button disappears doing this. Yes, it's nil. Why? Should I add the extension?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but it is unable to load your image for some reason.  You verified that the target membership includes your project?  You could try renaming the image.  Can you view the image in Xcode?

Comment: @vacawama I did rename it, same thing. Yes I can view it in the media assets folder.